# How to change join type when creating table relations, Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, join, vba, foreign-keys

I have created relations between tables in Access vba with codes `add constraint ...foreign key...references..`. But it does not do anything with the join type as the default join type remains inner join.

[image: Table relations, join type]

How can I define join type in Access vba when creating relations between tables?

thanks

Comment: My Access is in chinese but i think you can figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify such things, you need to use DAO, and not SQL.

Sample code to create a relation that right joins Table1 to Table2 on a field named ID in both tables, without referential integrity:

```vb
Dim rel As New Relation
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
rel.Attributes = dbRelationDontEnforce + dbRelationRight
rel.Name = "MyRelation"
rel.Table = "Table1"
rel.ForeignTable = "Table2"
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set fld = rel.CreateField("ID")
fld.Name = "ID"
fld.ForeignName = "ID"
rel.Fields.Append fld
db.Relations.Append rel
```